# Migrating SVN to GIT: Incorrect filenames with special characters

Tags: git-svn, special-characters, migrate

I'm trying to convert an existing SVN repository to GIT using `git-svn clone` but versioned files with special characters in the filename like "ö" are showing as "Ã¶" after migration. Obviously, git-svn saves the filenames "as is" - I assume that SVN stores filenames in UTF-8 (as done with the logs), but my Windows uses windows-1252 encoding.

Is it possible to force git-svn to change the filename encoding? Didn't find anything in the manuals.

Comment: Seems to be a issue with msysgit =/ http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80

Comment: @Carl Hörberg: You seem right. Tried it on Linux (UTF-8 locale) and it worked as expected. Could you please add this as an answer, so I can mark the question "solved"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be a issue with msysgit: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80

Although, git in Cygwin doesn't have this issue.